# Md5 implementation in C language for POS

Tags: c

Can any one tell me how to implement MD5 algorithm in a C program.I want a c Program which captures the given Password and converts its equivalent message digest and save. Actually i need this functionality for a POS Application development.

Comment: Have you thought to [Google for this](http://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=md5+c+implementation)?

Comment: Try using [Google](http://www.google.com) and searching for "C MD5 library".

Comment: Why do you want to hash a password with md5?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a public domain implementation of MD5 in C: [link](http://cvsweb.xfree86.org/cvsweb/cvs/lib/md5.c?rev=1.1.1.2).

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid saving the message digest straight away.

For common passwords, you'll likely to find databases to directly map back to the password - just search for 5ebe2294ecd0e0f08eab7690d2a6ee69 with Google or your favorite search engine as an example.

Include a salt to protect against that.

Comment: Even plain md5/sha1 with salt is very weak for password hashing.